# simplify: $ \lim_{x\to2} {x^3 - 3x -2 \over x^2 -4} $

Tags: calculus

$$ \lim_{x\to2} {x^3 - 3x -2 \over x^2 -4} $$

$$ \lim_{x\to2} {x^3 - 3x -2 \over (x+2) (x-2)} $$

If I can cancel out $x-2$ in denominator than I can get avoid getting $0$ in denominator. And apply the limit.

Comment: $2^3-3(2)-2=0$ so $x-2$ is a factor of $x^3-3x-2$. You can use synthetic division to find the quadratic factor of $x^3-3x-2$

Comment: Hint: $x^3 -3x - 2 = (x-2)(x+1)^2$, so $\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x^3-3x-2}{x^2 - 4} = \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{(x+1)^2}{x+2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$x^3-3x-2=(x-2)(x^2+2x+1)$$